# Eigenspace is a subspace of V - ψ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and let $V$ a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. Let $\phi, \psi:V\rightarrow V$ be linear operators, such that $\phi\circ\psi=\psi\circ\phi$.

Show that:

1. For $\lambda \in \text{spec}(\phi)$ it holds that $\text{Eig}(\phi, \lambda )\leq_{\psi}V$.
2. Let $n=\dim_{\mathbb{K}}V$ and $n=|\text{spec}(\phi)|$. Then $\psi$ is diagonalizable.

$$$$

At question 1 we have that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\phi$. We have that $\phi (v )=\lambda v$, for the respective eigenvector $v$.

Then we have that $\phi (v_1+v_2)=\lambda (v_1+v_2)=\lambda v_1+\lambda v_2=\phi (v_1)+\phi (v_2)$ and $\phi (cv_1)=\lambda (cv_1)=c\left (\lambda v_1\right )=c\phi (v_1)$.

Is everything correct so far? So it follows that $\text{Eig}(\phi, \lambda )\leq_{\psi}V$, right?

Could you give me a hint for question 2?

Answer (score 1):

Your first part looks fine.

For part $2$, it' clear that $\phi$ has $n$ distinct eigen values .

Let the eigen values be $\phi$ be $c_i,i=1,2,...,n$ where all $c_i$ are distinct.

Let the corresponding eigen vectors be $v_i,i=1,2,..,n$

I show that $v_i$ are also eigen vectors of $\psi$

First of all , I prove that for any two operators $T$ and $U$ on $V$ , if $TU=UT$ (i.e they commute), then $Range(U)$ and $Ker(U)$ is invariant under $T$

Proof:- Let $\beta \in Range(U)$

Then $\exists \alpha \in V$ such that $U(\alpha)=\beta$

Then $T(\beta)=TU(\alpha)=U(T(\alpha)) \in Range (U)$

Similarly,we show  for $Ker (U)$

Now here $\phi$ and $\psi$ commute, that gives $\psi$ commutes with $\phi-c_i I$ ,where I is identity operator.

Now $v_i \in Ker(\phi-c_i I)$, so the space generated by it $L(v_i)$ is invariant under $\psi$ for each $i$ and hence $v_i$ are eigen vectors for $\psi$.

Now since there is basis $\{v_i,i=1,2,..,n\}$ of $V$ which are all eigen vectors of $\psi$,so it is diagonisable.

Comment: I thought about the first part again and now I got stuck what is the index $\psi$ at $\text{Eig}(\phi, \lambda )\leq_{\psi}V$ ?

Comment: From your answer I assumed that the first part just asked $Eig(\phi, \lambda)$ to be shown as a subspace, but I have no idea about the index $\psi$ there..sorry !

Comment: I gave it some thought and the only reasonable answer I can think of is that  the first part is asking the eigen space $Eig(\phi, \lambda)$ to be shown as $\psi$ invariant subspace of $V$ , hence the index $\psi$ . which is what I have actually shown in my answer. For getting assured , you have to look for the notations from where you got your questions. Is that okay?

Comment: So we have to show that $Eig(\phi, \lambda)$ is $\psi$-invariant and a subspace of $V$, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I got stuck right now how to show that $\text{Eig}(\phi, \lambda)$ is $\psi$ invariant. Do we have to show that if $v\in \text{Eig}(\phi, \lambda)$ then $\psi (v)\in \text{Eig}(\phi, \lambda)$ ?